# Track multiple subdomains + tld Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, subdomain, visitors

** tld = top level domain

I am wanting to track my main domain and all of its subdomains (around 180) in Google Analytics.

I am wondering if it would be better to create 180+ profiles for each subdomain or would it be better to track them all through one profile?

**The reason I ask is:**

I need to easily access subdomain stats + the total amount of unique visitors PER subdomain

Want to see the total amount of unique visitors (including subdomains and tld)
Any ideas?

Comment: Possible bad news -- there used to be a limit of 50 profiles per analytics account (see https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/analytics/discuss-google-analytics-features-with-other-users/gJwuhFwpgL4). I'm not sure if there's currently still a limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usually the best practice with multiple subdomains is really to create a separate profile for each subdomain within a central UA.

Unfortunatelly, there is still a limit of 50 profiles, but if you have such an necessity, you can make contact with any of [Google´s Partners](http://www.google.com/intl/en/analytics/partners.html) and they can submit a request to increase your limit to 200.

Another solution, not as optimal as having many profiles, would be to create virtual pageviews that could id the subdomain and then apply advanced filters to segment the data.

Here at dp6 we are a certified parter, if you would like to [contact us](http://www.dp6.com.br/contato), please feel free to do so.